# install GD2 library php

Tags: php, gd2

Looked up some other posts about this. Said to restart apache after modifying ini.php file. my server host won't restart apache like suggests by other users, because it is a shared server.

Is there a work around?

Comment: If you don't have gd2 on your shared host, change for a better hoster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately if you do not have root access to the server then there appears to be no other way to install the GD2 library.

If it really is important to you, you can either make a request to your host to install it or get a VPS/Dedicated/Cloud based server.

Comment: alright, I am looking to resize large images to thumbnails. is it required to have the GD2 library to do so? I am a bit new to this...

Comment: thx, been trying to do the Imagick but not working properly, so will give another shot. then will try and get host to install GD2 in mean time. seems crazy that my host would not have some way to install it.